# How to merge a branch with other branch of the same parent but exclude a changeset alone in mercurial

Tags: mercurial, branch, changeset, hg-merge

I have a branch a1 whose parent branch is A. Now I have created another branch a2 from same parent A. I want to merge a1 with a2 excluding a chengeset from a1. Is there a way to partially merge a branch excluding a changeset?

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is no: merges work according to the graph topology, not the branch names.

The longer answer is still no, but it's worth drawing the topology.  Your description talks about branch parentage, but branches themselves do not have parent/child relationships.  Branches are just collections of commits, with each commit containing its branch name.  (*Commits* have parent/child, or more generally, ancestor/descendant, relationships.)  So:

> I have a branch a1 whose parent branch is A.

This really means that you have some commit(s) <rev-number(s)> whose branch name is `a1`, and one or more of those commits have parent commit(s) <different-rev-number(s)> whose branch name is `A`.  If we draw them we get, e.g.:

```
A:  ...--o--o--o
          \
a1:        o--o
```

> Now I have created another branch a2 from same parent A.

Again, this just means that you have yet more commits (with their rev-numbers) whose branch name is `a2`; at least one such commit has a parent whose branch-name is `A`; we might draw this any number of ways, but let's try this one:

```
a2:              o--o
                /
A:  ...--o--o--o
          \
a1:        o--o
```

> I want to merge a1 with a2 excluding a chengeset from a1.

You don't really merge *branches*.  Instead, you merge *commits*.  You do this while having some commit checked-out into the working tree—this working-tree copy is the *proposed next commit*—and you are, by definition, on some branch.  You then run `hg merge` and specify some other revision: a commit that is on this or any other branch.  Assuming the merge makes sense, Mercurial begins the merging process.  When the merge is done, the new commit will have your current branch as its branch, and will have the working-tree's parent commit as its first parent, and the supplied revision as its second-parent.

So here, you might `hg update a2` to select the tip of `a2` as the commit copied into the working tree.  The working-tree is a proposed, but not yet actual, new commit for `a2`, and its parent is the commit now marked `@`:

```
a2:              o--@
                /
A:  ...--o--o--o
          \
a1:        o--o
```

> Is there a way to partially merge a branch excluding a changeset?

You may select either of the two (we've only drawn two here) commits that are on `a1` as your target for the `hg merge` operation.  Let's say you select the *second* one, using `hg merge a1`:

```
a2:              o--@
                /
A:  ...--*--o--o
          \
a1:        o--●
```

The filled-in circle is the commit to merge; `@` is the parent of the working tree; so `*` is their merge base—the best common-ancestor commit.  Mercurial will compare the contents of the snapshot in `*` to the contents of the snapshot in `@` (or the working tree—these contents should be the same when you start the process), and also compare the contents of the snapshot in `*` to those in `●`.  These two comparisons each produce an en-masse changeset: the contents in `●` are modified from those in the `o` between `*` and `●`.  Merge will simply combine these two en-masse changesets (which are then applied to the base's content).

You can, of course, select the other `a1` commit for merging, but then you'll be using its snapshot, not the one for `●`.  This will effectively exclude the changes in `●`—probably not what you want.

Let's draw yet a third graph, since this particular one is a bit shallow for our purposes.  Suppose instead of just the two commits exclusive to `a1`, we have many.  But *one* of them, which we'll draw as `x` here, we'd like to *exclude* when doing the merge into `@`:

```
a2:              o--@
                /
A:  ...--*--o--o
          \
a1:        o--o--o--x--o--o--o   [want to merge this commit]
```

To achieve what you *do* want, you must first make *new* commits, perhaps on `a1`, perhaps on a new branch entirely.  These new commits will look like this:

```
a2:              o--@
                /
A:  ...--*--o--o
          \
           o--o--o--x--o--o--o
a1:               \
                   ----o--o--o
```

In this case, I've drawn the new commits as a new mini-branch *within* `a1`, but perhaps it would be clearer to make them on a new branch `a3`:

```
a2:              o--@
                /
A:  ...--*--o--o
          \
a1:        o--o--o--x--o--o--o
                  \
a3:                ----o--o--o
```

The three *new* commits, in both cases, are simply copies of the changesets that occur *after* commit `x`.  When using `a3`, the easy way to make these copies is to use `hg graft`.  Now we can pick the tip commit of `a3` as the one to merge into `a1`:

```
a2:              o--@
                /
A:  ...--*--o--o
          \
a1:        o--o--o--x--o--o--o
                  \
a3:                ----o--o--●
```

and the result of the merge will be a merge commit, which will tie back to both the old `@`—the new merge is the current commit so it is now `@`—and `●`:

```
a2:              o--o---------------@
                /                  /
A:  ...--*--o--o                  /
          \                      /
a1:        o--o--o--x--o--o--o  /
                  \            /
a3:                ----o--o---●
```

The merge *still* used the topology, not the branch names.

(This is a key realization for Mercurial: branch names merely *group commits together;* but it's the *graph topology* that really controls things.)

Comment: Nice, thorough, detailed answer!